# Three.js error: "Uncaught TypeError: THREE.InstancedMesh is not a constructor"

Tags: three.js, jsfiddle

in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ssccdd/cLzx7ygk/4/
I can't understand why I'm getting the error " Uncaught TypeError: THREE.InstancedMesh is not a constructor". I believe that `THREE.InstancedMesh` is part of three.min.js where it is imported.

for comparison here is a working example with no error, only three.min.js being imported, using THREE.InstancedMesh, for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/onirenaud/vagwtbmj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`THREE.InstancedMesh` was added with `r109`.

Your first fiddle uses `103dev` whereas the second (working) example uses the latest release.